# How i share my Wifi using application swift in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, sharing

Hi i need an logic for wifi sharing:
On my phone I can allow users near to me to connect to my wifi hotspot. i want to share my wifi through application. Is it possible ?

Comment: Only the user can turn on the hotspot using Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible unless you jailbreak your phone. The options to create a wifi hotspot are locked to carrier settings and are only available if you jailbreak your phone.

Comment: Thanks you save my time